# find and replace special characters powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a method that has an if statement that catches if it finds a special character. What I want to do now if find the position of the special characters and replace it with _A

Some Examples

- test# **becomes** test_A
- I#hope#someone#knows#the#answer# **becomes** I_Ahope_Asomeone_Aknows_Athe_Aanswer_A

or if it has more than one special character

- You?didnt#understand{my?Question# **becomes** You_Adidnt_Aunderstand_Amy_AQuestion_A

Would I have to loop through the whole string and when I reach that character change it to _A or is there a quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`#` is just a character like any other, you can use the `-replace` operator:

```
PS C:\>'I#hope#someone#knows#the#answer#' -replace '#','_A'
I_Ahope_Asomeone_Aknows_Athe_Aanswer_A
```

Regex is magic, you can define all the special cases you like (braces will have to be escaped):

```
PS C:\>'You?didnt#understand{my?Question#' -replace '[#?\{]','_A'
You_Adidnt_Aunderstand_Amy_AQuestion_A
```

So your function could look something like this:

```psh
function Replace-SpecialChars {
    param($InputString)

    $SpecialChars = '[#?\{\[\(\)\]\}]'
    $Replacement  = '_A'

    $InputString -replace $SpecialChars,$Replacement
}

Replace-SpecialChars -InputString 'You?didnt#write{a]very[good?Question#'
```

If you are unsure of which characters to escape, have the `regex` class do it for you!

```psh
function Replace-SpecialChars {
    param(
        [string]$InputString,
        [string]$Replacement  = "_A",
        [string]$SpecialChars = "#?()[]{}"
    )

    $rePattern = ($SpecialChars.ToCharArray() |ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join "|"

    $InputString -replace $rePattern,$Replacement
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the .NET string method `Replace()`:

```
'You?didnt#understand{my?Question#'.Replace('#','_A').Replace('?','_A').Replace('{','_A')
```

But I feel the regex way is more concise

Comment: that doesn't find the position of the special character as there could be more than more than 1 special character in the string

Comment: @davetherave why are you interested in the location if the replacement takes place as expected? I've updated the answer to show how you can expand it beyond just `#`

Comment: This answer addresses the question you asked.  If you really want the answer to some other question, then you need to go back and edit your OP.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am new to powershell so just needed it explaining